# Moving from Ace to Monaco Editor -> Replace Ace's enableBasicAutocompletion and enableLiveAutocompletion

Tags: angular, ace-editor, monaco-editor, ngx-monaco-editor

I'm replacing my Ace Editor with Monaco. the main used language in the editor is python.

When I used ace, enableBasicAutocompletion and enableLiveAutocompletion where set to true.
enableBasicAutocompletion - enable opening a pop up on ctrl+space
enableLiveAutocompletion - show drop down list with auto complete suggestions

I can't find the same config values in Monaco editor. It seems that drop down is being opened by default but only with local suggestions (words that where used before)